# Difference between two value in embedded document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

This is my collection:

```
 {
       "Id" : "001",
    "Data":[{
                        "updatedTime" : 1483209005,
                        "value" : 35
                    }, 
                    {
                        "updatedTime" : 1483209005,
                        "value" : 20
                    }
        ]

    }
```

This was i tried:

```
 db.A.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$Id",
        "Difference": { 
            "$sum": { 
                "$cond": [
                    { "$eq": [ "Data.$.value", 35.0 ] },
                    "$updatedTime", 
                    { "$cond": [
                        { "$eq": [ "Data.$.value", 20.0 ] },
                        { "$subtract": [ 0, "$updatedTime" ] },
                        0
                    ]}
                ]
            }
        }
    }}
])
```

But i get output like this:

```
{
    "_id" : "001",
    "Difference" : 0.0
}
```

I need to find difference bewteen two updatedDate fields in data array how to i do that?

Comment: What is  your mongod version? Do you always have two elements in your array?

Comment: version 3.4 and data array have only two fields

Comment: You said you only have  two elements in the array. And right now it is unclear what the expected result should be when the length of your array is greater than 2. You should consider to ask another question and I will be happy to help. I rolled back your last edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign each element in your array to a variable using the [`$let`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let) operator in order to access the subdocument field with "dot notation" can use the `$subtract` and [`$abs`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/abs). To get the first and second element, simply use the [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt) operator.

In the "in" expression you need to [`$subtract`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract/) the two values and return the absolute value using the `$abs` operator.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": "$Id",
        "Difference": {
            "$sum": {
                "$let": { 
                    "vars": { 
                        "first": { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$Data", 0 ] }, 
                        "second": { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$Data", 1 ] }
                    }, 
                    "in": { 
                        "$abs": { 
                            "$subtract": [
                                "$$first.updatedTime", 
                                "$$second.updatedTime"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }}
])
```

Comment: its possible to find multiple value and updatedTime  in data array and finaly sum the total result?

Answer (score -1):

As you said it will always have two elements, then do something like this --

```
    db.getCollection('test').aggregate([{$project: {diff: {$abs: {$subtract: [{$arrayElemAt: ['$Data.value', 0]}, {$arrayElemAt: ['$Data.value', 1]}]}}}}])
```

Comment: and the downvote because? what i think OP asked to calculate difference between 35, 20.